# WPF passing data from Window to a running User Control

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new in WPF world. I have a `UserControl` and a `Button` inside it. When button clicked, a selector `Window` open in new Window and running with `UserControl` at same time.
I want in second `window` when user select a value, pass this value back to `UserControl` then close window. How can I do this? is DataBinding with `INotifyPropertyChanged`class the best way? How can I implement this?

**solution:**
From Microsoft document and `delegate` and `EventHandler` meanings, I do the following. I have a `UserControl` with name `BuyFactor`. When user click `Add Item` new `Window` with name `AddItem` raised. When new item selected and when `Add This` clicked, I want to send Item Id back to `BuyFactor` with `EventHandler`:

**`BuyFactor` UserControl:**

```
public partial class BuyFactor: UserControl
{

    Dialogs.AddItem publisher;
    public TaqehBuyFactor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        publisher = new Dialogs.AddItem();

        publisher.RaiseCustomEvent += HandleCustomEvent;
    }

    void HandleCustomEvent(object sender, Dialogs.CustomEventArgs e)
    {
//Should change text when button clicked on Window (publisher)
        ProductName.Text = e.Message;
    }...}
```

**AddItem Window:**

```
 public partial class SelectTaqehDialog : Window
{

    public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> RaiseCustomEvent;
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Write some code that does something useful here
        // then raise the event. You can also raise an event
        // before you execute a block of code.
        OnRaiseCustomEvent(new CustomEventArgs("Did something"));
    }

    protected virtual void OnRaiseCustomEvent(CustomEventArgs e)
    {
        // Make a temporary copy of the event to avoid possibility of
        // a race condition if the last subscriber unsubscribes
        // immediately after the null check and before the event is raised.
        EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> handler = RaiseCustomEvent;

        // Event will be null if there are no subscribers
        if (handler != null)
        {
            // Format the string to send inside the CustomEventArgs parameter
            e.Message += String.Format(" at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());

            // Use the () operator to raise the event.
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }


private void addToFactor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

// Fire when Add This button clicked
                DoSomething();
            }
```

**And My `CustomEventArgs`:**

```
public class CustomEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public CustomEventArgs(string s)
    {
        message = s;
    }
    private string message;

    public string Message
    {
        get { return message; }
        set { message = value; }
    }
}
```

Pay attention that call `publisher.Show()` for creating new window.

Comment: Learn and use MVVM

Comment: pass the value back to UserControl invoking an event when something happens in window, to do that give an argument to the event and subscribe it from where the windows was instantiated

Comment: @ChristopherKiessling can you offer a simple sample code please?

Comment: of course! see the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// in MainWindow or somewhere
myUserControl.someBtn.Click += (se, a) => {
    var mw = new MyWindow();
    mw.Show();
    mw.myEvent += (myEventSender, myComboBoxFomMyWindow) => MessageBox.Show(myComboBoxFromMyWindow.SelectedItem as string);
};

// MyWindow
public event EventHandler<ComboBox> MyEvent;
public MyWindow() {
    myComboBox.SelectionChanged += (se, a) => MyEvent?.Invoke(this, myComboBox);
}
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Giving <ComboBox> to the event argument just as example, change it as your needs, even an array or your own class in case you want to pass multiple values

Comment: I'm just checking